# MySQL SELECT output next date per id in same row

Tags: mysql, select, join, ranking

I have the following table structure that I query on.

```
ID  Date        Before value    After value
1   2014-04-25  Win             Loss
1   2014-04-30  Loss            Win
1   2014-08-18  Win             Loss
1   2014-08-27  Loss            Remise
1   2014-09-05  Remise          Loss
2   2014-05-25  Win             Remise
2   2014-06-07  Remise          Win
2   2014-06-20  Win             Loss
```

As output of my select statement I want the following result:

```
ID  Start_Date  End_Date    After value
1   start       2014-04-25  Win
1   2014-04-26  2014-04-30  Loss
1   2014-05-01  2014-08-18  Win
1   2014-08-19  2014-08-27  Loss
1   2014-08-28  2014-09-05  Remise
1   2014-09-06  current     Loss
2   start       2014-05-25  Win
2   2014-05-26  2014-06-07  Remise
2   2014-06-08  2014-06-20  Win
2   2014-06-21  current     Loss
```

Of course the table has 1000's of records where it needs to go right. I tried with ranking and joining, but no luck yet. If there is a next row I somehow need to retrieve this value as start date +1.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/520b13/2

Comment: Would be a piece of cake with a modern DBMS (that supports `lead()`) but with MySQL this will be quite complicated and slow.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried? Any possibility of creating a SQLFiddle?

Comment: @Tanu http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/520b13/2

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses MySql inline variables to preserve the last ID and last date for comparison to the next record.

```
SELECT
      t.id,
      IF( @LastID = t.id, @LastDate, 'start     ' ) as StartDate,
      IF( NOT t.date = t2.date, t.date, 'current   ' ) as EndDate,
      t.after_value,
      @LastID := t.id as saveForNextLineID,
      @LastDate := t.date + INTERVAL 1 day as saveForNextDate
   from
      the_table t
         left join ( select id, max( date ) as date
                        from the_table
                        group by id ) t2
            ON t.id = t2.id,
      (select @LastID := 0, @LastDate := 'start     ' ) sqlvars
   order by
      t.id, 
      t.date
```

[SQL Fiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8905a/8)

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines somewhat but you might be able to use UNION to manually add a start and end date eg:

```
select * from mytable
union 
select DISTINCT ID,'2000-01-01' as `Date`,`Before value`,``After value` from mytable
union 
select DISTINCT ID,NOW() as `Date`,`Before value`,``After value` from mytable
```

Try Popping this in a sub-select and run your grouping code on that.

Comment: This is unfortunately not what I need.